# How do I use map with function with more than one parameter

Tags: clojure

I have the following method:

```
(defn area [x y] (* x y))
```

How do I iterate through a list with respect to the parameters number. Something like

```
(map area [2 5 6 6])
```

so it will make calculations like `(area 2 5)` and `(area 6 6)`, maybe vector is not the proper type to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
(map #(apply area %) (partition 2 [2 5 6 6]))
```

Comment: `partial` could be used instead of the anonymous function, depending on personal taste: `(map (partial apply area) (partition 2 [2 5 6 6])) ;=> (10 36)`

Comment: I didn't know about `partial`, but I do like it better than the anonymous function. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `partition` as some have suggested here but you might want to consider arranging the data differently. For example you could use a vector of vectors:

```
[[2 5] [6 6]]
```

Then you can change your `area` function to:

```
(defn area [[x y]] (* x y))
```

Now you can call that with one of your pairs: `(area [6 6])` and mapping over your vector is easy:

```
(map area [[2 5] [6 6]])
```

If for some reason you need `area` to take two parameters instead of a vector you can do something like this:

```
(map #(apply area %) [[2 5] [6 6]])
```

To me that's still simpler than using `partition`.

Comment: Depending on the OP's data source, he may have to use `partition` to get the data into that form anyway :-)

Comment: True, although the OP did suggest that maybe a vector wasn't the appropriate type. That made me think there might be some flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

`map` requires a separate sequence parameter for each parameter that the function expects:

```
(map [2 6] [5 6])
```